# Firefox 47.0 bugs in XHR in HTTPS to HTTPS (CORS) scenario

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, ssl

I make a cross-domain XHR from a secure domain to a secure domain.

I thought it is 
[Cross-domain XHR to https address (SSL) fails in Firefox (works in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065016/cross-domain-xhr-to-https-address-ssl-fails-in-firefox-works-in-chrome) but it isn't. The certificates are trusted.

A POST request with 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' in FF47.0 does not get the 'Content-Length' set and is therefore responded by a 411 by the webserver.

A POST request with 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' works fine.

But: (And this is extremely weird for me) A POST request with 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and a custom field set like 'X-Foo' again does not get set the 'Content-Length' field.

Is this the expected behavior?

Look at the code: (CodePen: http://codepen.io/chrispillen/pen/dXBZkv)

```
  /* serialize object as url encoded NVP */
  var serialize = function(obj) {

      var str = [];

      for(var p in obj) {

          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {

              str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));

          }

      }

      return str.join("&");

  };

  /* url to api */
  var apiUrl = "https://sandbox.api.kehrwasser.com/kanubox/v1";

  /* credentials */
  var credentials = { mail: "user@mailserver.com", password: "12345" };    

  /* xhr request from https to https */
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("POST", apiUrl + "/users/auth/");

  var data;

  /* combination 1 - not working - no Content-Length field set by Firefox 47.0 */
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  data = JSON.stringify(credentials);

  /* combination 2 - working - Content-Length field set by Firefox 47.0 */
  // request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  // data = serialize(credentials);

  /* combination 3 - not working - no Content-Length field set by Firefox 47.0 */
  //request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  //request.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Secret", "foobar");
  //data = serialize(credentials);

  request.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.

      if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {

          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "DONE";

      } else {

          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "LOADING...";

      }

  }

  request.send(data);
```

Comment: works for me with Firefox 48

Comment: Ah forgot to mention: On Macosx